# Can I assign a cleanup handler to a boost thread?

Tags: boost, pthreads, boost-thread

In `pthreads` I can use cleanup handle functions and put them ona Stack with `pthread_cleanup_push()`.
Is there a similar concept with boost threads?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could mimic it by wrapping your thread function into an other function, that calls your function and then your cleanup handler.

An other solution would be to add what every you need into your cleanup handler, and put that into the destructor of a thread local storage. But if you have to call that cleanup handler for all threads, you have to make sure such a thread local variable is really used and that would boil down to wrapping your thread function.

If you want to replace pthread_cleanup_push() and pop() calls, I would go for constructors and destructors, so

```
void roll_back( void* i );
{
   do_rollback( *(int*)i );
}

void thread()
{
    int roll_back_arg = 4;
    pthread_cleanup_push( &roll_back, &roll_back_arg );

    // transaction

    pthread_clean_up_pop( 0 );
}
```

could be translated into:

```
struct roll_back_guard
{
    roll_back_guard( int arg  ) : arg_( arg ), commit_( false ) {}

    void commit() {
        commit_ = true;
    }

    ~roll_back_guard() {
        if ( !commit_ )
            do_rollback( arg_ );
    }
};

void thread()
{
    roll_back_guard guard( 4 );

    // transaction
    guard.commit();
}
```

Usually this pattern is called scope guard.

Comment: I am trying to move code from c to c++ and want to use boost::thread. The code uses `pthread_cleanup_push()` and `pthread_cleanup_pop()` to surround the main code of a thread.

Comment: @tzippy in c++ surround this code by { }, and put the above "scope guard" object definition in the beginning of the block.